# Databricks Error: Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same target row in the Delta table conflicting way

Tags: pyspark, merge, azure-databricks, delta-lake, merge-conflict-resolution

I am attempting to carry the following merge statement with PySpark on the table below (please note, this is my first attempt at creating a table on Stack Overflow using HTML snippet, so I have it shows the table - I think you have to click on RUN CODE SNIPPET to view the table).

```
try:
  #Perform a merge into the existing table
  if allowDuplicates == "true":
    (deltadf.alias("t")
       .merge(
        partdf.alias("s"),
        f"s.primary_key_hash = t.primary_key_hash")
      .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
     .execute()
    )
  else:
    (deltadf.alias("t")
       .merge(
        partdf.alias("s"),
        "s.primary_key_hash = t.primary_key_hash")
      .whenMatchedUpdateAll("s.change_key_hash <> t.change_key_hash")
      .whenNotMatchedInsertAll().
     execute()
    )
```

However, I keep on getting the error:

> Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to
> modify the same target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting
> ways. By SQL semantics of Merge, when multiple source rows match on
> the same target row, the result may be ambiguous as it is unclear
> which source row should be used to update or delete the matching
> target row.

Can someone take a look at my code and let me know why I keep on getting the error please.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252" />
  <title>Export Data</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .h {
      color: Black;
      font-family: Tahoma;
      font-size: 8pt;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: Silver;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    
    td {
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: Silver;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    
    .rh {
      background-color: White;
      vertical-align: Top;
      color: Black;
      font-family: Tahoma;
      font-size: 8pt;
      text-align: Left;
    }
    
    .rt {
      background-color: White;
      vertical-align: Top;
      color: Black;
      font-family: Tahoma;
      font-size: 8pt;
      text-align: Left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<bodybgColor=White>
  <p class="h"></p>
  <table cellspacing="0">

    <tr class="rh">
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>SinkCreatedOn</td>
      <td>SinkModifiedOn</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rt">
      <td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
      <td>15/12/2022 14:02:51</td>
      <td>15/12/2022 14:02:51</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rt">
      <td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
      <td>16/12/2022 18:30:59</td>
      <td>16/12/2022 18:30:59</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rt">
      <td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
      <td>16/12/2022 18:55:04</td>
      <td>16/12/2022 18:55:04</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rt">
      <td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
      <td>20/12/2022 16:26:45</td>
      <td>20/12/2022 16:26:45</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rt">
      <td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
      <td>22/12/2022 17:27:45</td>
      <td>22/12/2022 17:27:45</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rt">
      <td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
      <td>22/12/2022 17:57:48</td>
      <td>22/12/2022 17:57:48</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <p class="h"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am going to use the following dedup code as suggested:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

df2 = partdf.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("primary_key_hash").orderBy("Id")))
df3 = df2.filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")
display(df3)
```

In order to make the code work with my merge statement would it need to look like the following:

```
try:
  #Perform a merge into the existing table
  if allowDuplicates == "true":
    (deltadf.alias("t")
       .merge(
        df3.alias("s"),
        f"s.primary_key_hash = t.primary_key_hash")
      .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
     .execute()
    )
  else:
    (deltadf.alias("t")
       .merge(
        df3.alias("s"),
        "s.primary_key_hash = t.primary_key_hash")
      .whenMatchedUpdateAll("s.change_key_hash <> t.change_key_hash")
      .whenNotMatchedInsertAll().
     execute()
    )
```

You will notice the I have removed the `partdf` from the merge statement and replace it with `df3`

Comment: Hi Sharma, as you know, I posted that question some time ago :-). The difference between now and then is that the problem was discovered to be caused by duplicates on the primary key. However, as you can see if you 'Run code snippet' I don't have any duplicates on the Primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the scenario and got same error.

[image]

According to the above problem, ***there shouldn't be any duplicate fields in the Source table that you are comparing in the Target table while performing a MERGE operation on it***. The SQL engine automatically performs this check to prevent erroneous modifications and inconsistent data.

The simple solution is **De-duplication logic should thus be present before the MERGE process to avoid this problem**. You may quickly try to eliminate duplicates by using `window functions`, `dropduplicates fuction` dropping duplicated rows or any other logic in accordance with your needs:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

df2 = partdf.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("P_key").orderBy("Id")))
df3 = df2.filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")
 
display(df3)
```

[image]

**Executed successfully with above created dataframe:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pratik, thanks for reaching out. Going to try this suggestion in the next few hours.

Comment: Hi @Pratik, your dedup statement appears work really well. I'm just having a problem with where to add the df3 to my merge statement. I have updated the question with where I thought I would include the df3 variable. Looking forward to your response

Comment: yes, you just need to replace `partdf` from the merge statement and with `df3`

Comment: Hi @Pratik, I just did that and it worked. Thanks sooooo much mate.

Comment: Hi @Pratik, just wanted to say thank you again.

Comment: Hi @Pratik, you code works, however I was wondering if you could explain what the code is actually doing:
```df2 = partdf.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("P_key").orderBy("Id")))
df3 = df2.filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")```