# PySpark Code Modification to Remove Nulls

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I received help with following PySpark to prevent errors when doing a Merge in Databricks, see here

[Databricks Error: Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same target row in the Delta table conflicting way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75072866/databricks-error-cannot-perform-merge-as-multiple-source-rows-matched-and-attem/75078955?noredirect=1#comment132498136_75078955)

I was wondering if I could get help to modify the code to drop NULLs.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

df2 = partdf.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("P_key").orderBy("Id")))
df3 = df2.filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you identified the reason why the merge is failing? In my experience it's because the match condition is not targeting a unique record (joins on >1 row) in the target table

Comment: Hi @Chris, I didn't make myself clear. The code I posted is working perfectly fine. I would just like help modifying the code to remove NULLS if the 'P_Key' contains NULLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The code that you are using does not completely delete the rows where `P_key` is null. It is applying the row number for `null` values and where row number value is 1 where `P_key` is null, that row is not getting deleted.

[image]

- You can instead use the `df.na.drop` instead to get the required result.

```
df.na.drop(subset=["P_key"]).show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

**To make your approach work**, you can use the following approach. Add a row with least possible unique `id` value. Store this id in a variable, use the same code and add additional condition in filter as shown below.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,when,col
df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("dbfs:/FileStore/sample1.csv")
#adding row with least possible id value.
dup_id = '0'
new_row = spark.createDataFrame([[dup_id,'','x','x']], schema = ['id','P_key','c1','c2'])

#replacing empty string with null for P_Key
new_row = new_row.withColumn('P_key',when(col('P_key')=='',None).otherwise(col('P_key')))
df = df.union(new_row) #row added

#code to remove duplicates
df2 = df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("P_key").orderBy("id")))
df2.show(truncate=False)

#additional condition to remove added id row.
df3 = df2.filter((df2.rn == 1) & (df2.P_key!=dup_id)).drop("rn")
df3.show()
```

[image]